# How to get device type using SNMP using C#?

Tags: c#, network-programming, snmp, net-snmp

my program can find the sysObjectID of my device the oid is given 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.1.1.3.1.1.

Question: How to know the device type if i have the objectID of the device using C# ?

Thanks!

Comment: On Windows? or on *nix?

Comment: Windows using C# visual studio

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up your own device OID database to store OID to device mappings or utilize a third party web service.

http://www.oidview.com/mibs/311/MSFT-MIB.html

You can see from above link that `1.3.6.1.4.1.311.1.1.3.1.1` is a Windows workstation machine.

Comment: hmm is there any way to do it? third party database do you mean sql server management studio?

Comment: Of course not. I mean a general web service that can help you query device information by OID. Just edited my answer.

Comment: As far as I know there is currently no free web service for you to consume. I am planning to set up such a service, but it will be commercial, not free.